# How can I remove an Object from a MongoDB array without $pull?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I'm trying to make a social media app, so I wrote a route that allows users to like posts, but If someone already liked it and pressed "like" again - It should remove the like, right? The point is - I can't use `$pull` since it uses `findByIdAndUpdate`, which can only be used if likes have their own separated model, but I don't have it because I think that overworks db a bit.

I use `for` to cycle trough an array and scan an Id of an Object and validate if it matches an Id of the logged user

```
const post = await Post.findById(request.params.post_id)

for (let i = 0; i < post.likes.length; i++) {

        if (post.likes[i].userId === request.user.id) {
            // Remove post.likes.[i] from the database completely
        }
        
}
```

Here is how post looks like in Mongo documents:

```
{  "userId": "627eae4ed5b20f818d7a8142",  "title": "Simple Post Title",  "body": "Whatever",  
"likes": [{      "userId": "627eae4ed5b20f818d7a8142",      "likedAt": "14:58:20"    }],  }
```

If there is something else I need to provide - don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: why `findByIdAndUpdate` is the only option? Can you use some other ways like `update` or `save` ?

Comment: Hmm, I don't know, I will try it rn, be back with the results

Comment: Actually, no. `Update` still applies to the Collection itself, which I don't have for the comments.

Comment: Wait, I'm an idiot. I DO have it, omg. Thanks a lot, question closed...

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind guys! I did it, I only needed to update the Post collection, nothing more!

```
for (let i = 0; i < post.likes.length; i++) {

        if (post.likes[i].userId === request.user.id) {
            
            Post
                .findByIdAndUpdate(post._id, {
                    $pull: { likes: post.likes[i] } 
                }, {
                    new: true,
                    runValidators: true
                })
                .then((updated_post) => {
                    response.status(200).json({ success: true, updated_post: updated_post })
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    return next(
                        new ErrorResponse(`An error occurred while updating the post`, 400)
                    )
                })
        }

    }
```

It does gives me an error, but I think I'll manage

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
```